# Safari 7.1 on MAC Computers causes navigation Issues with SharePoint 2010 -

Tags: browser-compatibility, browsers

Our Mac user updated there safari browsers to 7.1 and now the navigation doesn't work any more in SharePoint 2010.
    I have followed the solution [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tehnoonr/archive/2014/10/27/safari-7-1-on-mac-computers-causes-multiple-issues-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

But no luck. I did create the safari.browser file and added it to the appropriate folder and made an edit in the compat.browser butstill users are still having issues.

Do I need to change anything in this folder too? C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers

I have created a test custom page in SharePoint to get the bowser details and this is what I get

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/600.3.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1.3

Safari/537.85.12

Browser: AppleMAC-Safari

Id: safari600_bugfix

I cant see the AppleWebKit/600 in any of the compat.browser or Mozilla browser file

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your post has saved me a lot of grief by pointing to that MSDN blog post and the crucial "dummy edit" step.

Comment: Was trying to add - back to your question - there's no need to change the file in the Microsoft.NET folder. I've tried the fix as described and it works in our environment. From your description you've done everything right as well - two questions though:
1) Can you clarify what you mean by "the appropriate folder" (where you added your safari.browser)? I assume the virtual directory App_Browsers for your web app?
2) Your edit in the compat.browser was just the "dummy edit"?
Note, there is no AppleWebKit/600 in the compat.browser, it's wrongly picked up by the regex as described in the blog